# I Know I Can Make an Empty Branch in Git, Should I?

Tags: git, branch

I have some code that is Java EE 5. I want to start porting it to 6.

I was thinking I would do this:

1. Make a new empty branch (no code in it).
2. Start writing the 6 code on that branch, no rebasing, etc.
3. Make topic branches, rebasing/merging to the version branch.
4. When it's done, make a final version branch from master (of the old version) and delete master.
5. Make master from the new code.

Does this sound loopy? The project is one war and 2 jar projects. I'd really rather not make 3 new repositories for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up making another repository. There is no real reason to try to deliver a completely different codebase from the same repo for one simple reason: no intention of putting any more effort into the Java EE 5 version.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, your system seems convoluted. Why not just branch 6 from 5, make topic branches from 6, cherry pick commits into 5 when necessary, and otherwise do a rolling rebase on top of the 5 branch?

You seem to be thinking like an SVN user here.

Comment: Or, if you really really think that the 6 version shouldn't have the 5 version in its history (for some bizarre reason, despite surely having lots of common code), just make a new repo.

Comment: um, yeah, thanks for the dimestore psych, lemme go take a Dianetics test and see if they can clear me of my svn warp. Seriously? That makes < zero sense.

Comment: The main reason is, um, once I change the dependencies in the pom to point to the 6 equivalents, none of the 5 code will compile.. wait, did I lose you at compile? Thanks, Guys.

Comment: Yep, being snarky is definitely the way to get the help you want. I answered your question, you just don't understand why the answer is correct. Good luck getting it figured out.

Comment: I love when someone comes on doling snarky babytalk, gets a little back, then throws the 'you're snarky' card. Love the pic, Bro. Looks like you're doing Lancelot Link in Summer Stock.Thanks again.